# How to avoid a chained apply when selecting from multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, multi-index

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ind1': list('AAABBBCCC'),
    'ind2': list(map(int, list('123123123'))),
    'val1': [0, 1, 2, -1, -4, -5, 10, 11, 4],
    'val2': [0.1, 0.2, -0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, -0.1, 2, 0.1]
})

df = df.set_index(['ind1', 'ind2'])

           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
A    1        0   0.1
     2        1   0.2
     3        2  -0.2
B    1       -1   0.1
     2       -4   0.2
     3       -5   0.2
C    1       10  -0.1
     2       11   2.0
     3        4   0.1
```

I want to select all entries for which the absolute value of differences between the values in `val1` are increasing.

I currently do it as follows:

```
m_incr = (
    df.groupby('ind1')['val1']
      .apply(lambda x: np.diff(abs(x)))
      .apply(lambda x: all(eli > 0 for eli in x))
)

df_incr = df[m_incr[df.index.get_level_values('ind1')].values]
```

which gives me the desired outcome:

```
           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
A    1        0   0.1
     2        1   0.2
     3        2  -0.2
B    1       -1   0.1
     2       -4   0.2
     3       -5   0.2
```

My question is whether there is a more straightforward/efficient way that avoids the chained `apply`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`:

```
mask = df.groupby('ind1')['val1'].transform(lambda x: (np.diff(abs(x)) > 0).all())
```

And then filter by mask with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[mask])
```

All together:

```
print (df[df.groupby('ind1')['val1'].transform(lambda x: (np.diff(abs(x)) > 0).all())])
```

---

```
           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
A    1        0   0.1
     2        1   0.2
     3        2  -0.2
B    1       -1   0.1
     2       -4   0.2
     3       -5   0.2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (mask)
ind1  ind2
A     1        True
      2        True
      3        True
B     1        True
      2        True
      3        True
C     1       False
      2       False
      3       False
Name: val1, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
print(df[df.groupby('ind1')['val1'].transform(lambda x: x.abs().is_monotonic).astype(bool)])
```

Comment: @Cleb Happy to help :P

Comment: @Cleb I use `is_monotonic` which is the only difference between mine hand jezraels

Comment: Interestingly, it is slightly slower than the other solution (should of course test for a bigger `df` as this one is very small).

Comment: @Cleb Try making it bigger and see the difference.